# Why can't we edit questions that we deleted?

Tags: support, edits

We can edit questions *others* have deleted, but it would be helpful to be able to edit questions while they are deleted. This could be useful for redeeming questions while they are deleted so we don't have to undelete it first and have others judge us while we are editing the question.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [the Stack Exchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296101/why-can-i-not-edit-a-self-deleted-question) this is to stop spammers from creating innocuous posts, immediately deleting them, editing their spam into the post some time later and then undeleting their submarine spam.

If you have a self-deleted post that you want to improve and undelete, edit it offline and then undelete it and update it immediately with the offline copy.

Comment: But spammers can't undelete their posts that were deleted by community and locked and then lose 100 reputation. And how about letting high rep users editing our own deleted questions because I am not a spammer.

Comment: True, but that's not the situation you describe in your question, there you're talking about self deleted posts. You may not be a spammer but various high rep users have rage quit i.e. vandalised their posts before disappearing.

Comment: I see one week point in the suggestion of editing it offline. I would do it, but also want the "source" code of it, with all `**`, `_`, `, and so on, which I cannot access because I cannot edit the question.

Comment: @Enrico undelete it, copy it, delete it again.